# Use custom schema name with Azure mobile service request object execute method

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Is it possible to use custom database schema name with request.execute() method?

For all the cases with Azure mobile service till now, i've always used the DB schema name same as Mobile Service name. I've a case now where the DB schema name is different than mobile service name and was wondering if I can still use request.execute() method with some customization.

I know that i can always use mssql.query() to run custom queries but I was wondering if its possible to use custom schema name with "request" object in table scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible.  The request.execute method is only available on a table request (see [MSDN Docs on request object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554218.aspx) under Mobile Services) as opposed to a Custom API call.  The table object in mobile service is linked directly to one of the tables in the attached Azure SQL DB which utilizes the schema name of the mobile service.  I don't think you can override this.  As you point out you can use mssql to query or work against other tables within the same database, or even other databases.

On a side note the tables object is available, but also seems to be scoped to the same schema name and you can't get at tables from other schemas.

It might be possible that there is a way to get the default for the schema name to be something other than the mobile service name (not that I know of though), but as for a one off ability to tell request to use a different schema, not at this time.

Comment: Thanks MikeWo. I was thinking along the same lines too but posted question to see if there is some details I'm missing and somebody has already tried this. Since the Azure mobile service api is based on open source express.js, i was hopeful somebody knows work-around or has more insight. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Mike is correct. The table scripts are bound to the schema named after the mobile service - since the DB user created in the database when the service was created is only granted access to that schema, not to the rest of the database. You can consider adding this feature request in the Azure feedback at http://feedback.azure.com/forums/216254-mobile-services, or vote up one of the existing requests (the one at http://feedback.azure.com/forums/216254-mobile-services/suggestions/5439605-ability-to-customize-database-schema-name is similar to what you need)

Comment: I will vote up this feature. Thanks carlosfigureria.